# Manipulate and DynamicImage

Tags: manipulate, image-processing, dynamic

I would like to use DynamicImage within Manipulate, but have been unable to get the contents of DynamicImage to update. This basic example demonstrated the problem:

`Manipulate[Image[RandomReal[{0, i}, {100, 100}]], {i, 0, 1}]`

Updates upon adjusting the control slider, whereas

`Manipulate[DynamicImage@Image[RandomReal[{0, i}, {100, 100}]], {i, 0, 1}]`

does not.

I would much appreciate any help - Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Manipulate[With[{i = i}, 
  DynamicImage@Image[RandomReal[{0, i}, {100, 100}]]], {i, 0, 1}]
```

or

```
Manipulate[DynamicImage @ Image[RandomReal[{0, #}, {100, 100}]] & @ i, {i, 0, 1}]
```

or

```
Manipulate[DynamicImage@Image[RandomReal[{0, j}, {100, 100}]] /. j -> i, {i, 0, 1}]
```

[image]